How to subscribe to object node with OPCUA using Python?
I want to subscribe to an Object node in Python.
I want to output the values ​​of variable nodes of the object node in datachange_notification. Is it possible?
If there is a way, please let me know.
I tried as below, but the handler does not work properly.
from opcua import Client

client = Client("opc.tcp://1111.1111.1111.1111:1000")
client.connect()

class SubHandler(object):
    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        # print client.get_node("ns=2;ABC.T1") # variable node
        # print client.get_node("ns=2;ABC.T2") # variable node
        # print client.get_node("ns=2;ABC.T3") # variable node

node = client.get_node("ns=2;ABC") # object node
nodes = []
nodes.append(node)
handler = SubHandler()
subscription = client.create_subscription(500, handler)
handle = subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes)


You can not subscripe to a object for datachanges. If you want to get all changes from child variables you can do this:
from opcua import Client

client = Client("opc.tcp://1111.1111.1111.1111:1000")
client.connect()

class SubHandler(object):
    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        print(node, val)

node = client.get_node("ns=2;ABC") # object node
nodes = node.get_children(nodeclassmask=ua.NodeClass.Variable) # Collect all child variables
handler = SubHandler()
subscription = client.create_subscription(500, handler)
handle = subscription.subscribe_data_change(nodes)
while 1:
    # Stay connected to recive datachange notifications
    time.sleep(1.0)

